# Append the element with each function jQuery

Tags: jquery

I know this is a simple work around but I couldn’t find the right path. Please help!

I have a HTML structure like this

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to append the `<img>` inside the grand-child1 `<span>` on 1st two `<main>` divs.

If I use the following jQuery `<img>` are appearing twice in all `<main>` divs

```
$("img").appendTo(".grand-child1");
```

So, I have used each function like this. But nothing works for me.

```
$(".main img").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).find('img').appendTo(this).closest(".grand-child1");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic in the second example is almost there, but not quite right. The `this` keyword already references the `img` element, so there's no need to `find()` it. Also, the `.child1` element is a sibling of the `img` so you can use `siblings()` instead of `closest()` (which is for finding parent elements).  Finally the `.child1` element needs to be provided as an argument to `appendTo()`.

Try this example:

```js
$(".main img").each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).siblings(".child1"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <span class="child1">some content</span>
  <span class="child2">some content</span>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span class="child1">some content</span>
  <span class="child2">some content</span>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <span class="child1">some content</span>
  <span class="child2">some content</span>
</div>
```

*Update:*

Given the new HTML in the question, you would just need to amend the DOM traversal logic. Use `prev()` and `find()` instead of `siblings()`:

```js
$(".main img").each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('.parent').find(".grand-child1"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rory. But sorry my mistake, I have not given the proper html structure, now I have edited my question. Can you please check once.

Comment: Updated the answer for that case too

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to iterate your `.main` like:

```js
$(".main").each((i, el) => $(".grand-child1", el).append($("img", el)));
```

where the jQuery format `$("selector", el)` is the same as `$(el).find("selector")`

Demo time:

```js
$(".main").each((i, el) => $(".grand-child1", el).append($("img", el)));
```

```css
.grand-child1 {background: gold;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjX6DjQWxlXWc82JMbuluX6Jmgeg305J6utvwOgjg=k-s64" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjX6DjQWxlXWc82JMbuluX6Jmgeg305J6utvwOgjg=k-s64" />
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">some content</div>
    <div class="child2"><span class="grand-child1">some content</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the new approach, Working as expected !